# PGP Desktop Whole disk Encryption paused on a toshiba ultrabook z935

Tags: windows-7, pgp, toshiba-laptop, ultrabook, pgp-desktop

I have a Toshiba z930 Ultrabook with PGP Desktop installed for whole disk encryption. It installed correctly, and started encrypting but it stays paused. If I reboot, it shows me the PGP desktop username, password, domain screen. If I enter in my credentials, it allows me to get into windows but encryption remains paused.

If I click on resume, it lets me enter a password, accepts it but then it doesn't do anything.

One suspicious thing is that in the 'Select disk or partition to encrypt' box, it says, C: 120B fixed disk. Unknown Bus: TOSHIBA THNSNS12...

Do I need to change something in the BIOS, or install any drivers so that it doesn't see it as an Unknown Bus?

Comment: Do you have Symantec installed?

Comment: I had symantec endpoint protection installed. I uninstalled it but am experiencing the same problem. The log shows 'user resumed encryption' and then immediately, 'user finished encryption'

Comment: Seems it is a bug or an incompatibility http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/pgp-wont-resume-whole-disk-encryptionunknown-bus